# How to handel redirects in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape a specific site. After a few requests, the site tries to redirect my requests to my own IP. At this point, I wish to change my credentials with `login`  function. But I am unable to do it anyway. I have tried `errback` to call the `login`, but I don't know how to properly trigger an error for such redirections. can anyone please provide a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a `middleware` and inside `process_response` check `response.status` and re-schedule requests. Most probably you will need to use proxies, looks like you are banned

Comment: Yes, I agree that I would need proxies. Coming to the login problem, do you have any idea how to call a spider function from inside a middleware? because I have to make a post request to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You can process responses in [middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response)

Make sure you have enable your middleare in your `settings.py` or in your spider, to do in Spider do this

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "spider_name_here"

    custom_settings = {

        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER.middlewares.MyMiddleware': 300,
        },
    }
```

contents of `middleware.py`

```
class MyMiddleware(object):


    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        pass   

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):    

        if response.status in [403, or any response]:

            req = request.copy()

            return request

        else:

            return response
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.